# Binary seach not working for a particular output

Tags: c++, binary-search

Getting unexpected output just for a single input in binary search. When I enter {1,2,3,4,5} as input in array in binary search program then it shows element not present for only the input'2' even when element is present. Trying on codeblocks.

I have tried tracing the code in iteration and I don't understand why is this not working and if the variable (pos is my case) value is changing or not.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int last,fin,beg=0,mid,pos=-1,i,*a;

    cout<<"Enter the size of array: ";
    cin>>last;

    a=new int[last];

    cout<<"Enter the elements in array"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<last;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];                            
    }

    cout<<endl<<"Enter the element you want to find: ";
    cin>>fin;

    for(i=beg;i<=last;i++)
    {

        mid=(beg+last)/2;

        if(a[mid]==fin)
        {
            pos=mid;
        }
        else if(a[mid]>fin)
        {
            last=mid-1;
        }
        else
        {
            beg=mid+1;
        }
    }

    if(pos==-1)
    {
        cout<<"Element not present in array"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"element found "<<fin<<" at "<<pos+1<<" position"<<endl;
    }

    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that output of 2 should be : element found 2 at 2 position when I enter size (variable last) as 5 and elements as 1,2,3,4,5 . I am getting output : Element not present in array.

Comment: your loop is incorrect. you should loop while beg <=last

Comment: you shouldn't do dynamic allocations yourself, consider using a smart pointer or best containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop to this:

```
while (beg <= last) {
    int mid = (beg + last) / 2;
    if (a[mid] == fin) {
        pos = mid;
        break;              // break where you find the element in the array
    }
    else if (a[mid] > fin) last = mid - 1;
    else beg = mid + 1;
}
```

Your loop is incorrect. You are changing the bounds for searching in the loop (`beg` and `last`). So, to check if you can't search any further, you need to check whether `beg` has crossed `last` in which case, you will stop the search.

Also, in your code, `a` is an array allocated using `new`, but you are calling `delete a` instead of `delete[] a`.